# My PHP curl Post request didnt work as expected

Tags: php, curl, post

I try to send a post request to another php page with the following code:

```
$vars = ['val1' => 'myval'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But on the target page,  `var_dump($_POST);` will output only "1". I had expected something like:
`array(val1 = myval)` or something similar. So that i can check with `isset($_POST["val1"])` if this exists and contains "myval".

Any ideas whats wrong with the request?

**Edit:**
I have now changed my code to the following:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'foo'=>'bar',
    'baz'=>'boom',
    'cow'=>'milk',
    'php'=>'hypertext processor');
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "target.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

And in target.php:

```
<?php
echo print_r($_POST, true));
?>
```

But there is no response. Both files are in the same dir at the server.

Comment: This should work. How do you check what the response of the post-request is?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `curl_setopt()` doesn't accept such complext types as `array` ;) You need to present your data in form of a query string: `"postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3"`.

```php
$format = http_build_query($vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $format);
```

or

```php
$format = "val1=my-value"; // be careful to create proper encoding
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $format);
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) it can also be an array though.

Comment: You're right. "Passing an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` will encode the data as `multipart/form-data`, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`."

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, you don't need to set `CURLOPT_POST` as well. In fact, setting it **after** will result in a potentially incorrect header being sent.

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` accepts an array, and will set the Content-Type header to `multipart/form-data` if one is provided. Later, setting `CURLOPT_POST` will overwrite this to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and means that the PHP script at the other end will expect data encoded as an HTTP query-string. This is why you're having problems.

You can fix this either by encoding `$vars` correctly before sending (using `http_build_query`, as in the other answer), or just remove the call to set `CURLOPT_POST`. I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: Yay C APIs... NOT! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think, i got it. When i set as target something like "target.php", data was not send. But when i use a complete URL, like https://myserver.com/target.php, this will work as expected. Sometimes, its to easy... sorry for stealing your time.